# Which is the correct Options 's "Hydraulics" field in EPANET?

Tags: postgresql

Which parameter has to be given into Options 's "Hydraulics" field in EPANET?
Has it to be only a name or a complete file name with the extension?
In my case .rpt doesn't work, neither without the extension (nor with a path).
[I am working with giswater, that generate new db in postgreSQL, files for EPANET and a .qgs]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The hydraulics parameter of [OPTIONS] target is available only if you use the command line of EPANET software. If you try to load the INP file using the the Windows EPANET gui will appear a message like this:

Error Report for File *.inp

Error 201 at line XXX:
[OPTIONS]

but it is not a problem to run successfully your EPANET project

Comment: Thank you @xtorret. So, you say there's no way to have the field compiled and run EPANET by gui..